# how to set the integer value for transaction isolation level

Tags: java, jdbc

when I print the isolation level

```
 DatabaseMetaData dbMetaData = conn.getMetaData();
             if (dbMetaData                         .supportsTransactionIsolationLevel(Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE)) {
                     System.out.println("Transaction Isolation level= "
                                     + conn.getTransactionIsolation());
                     System.out.println(dbMetaData.getDefaultTransactionIsolation());
             }
```

for the connection I get an integer value 4
and for the database I get a value 2

I want to set the isolation level as SERIALIZABLE as it seems to work for most of the problems(that's what i heard anyways :-/) but i am not getting as to how to set it as its asking for a int value

```
conn.setTransactionIsolation(level);
```

what does the integer levels refer to and in which order to the transaction levels? I am using mysql database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Connection` class should have all the isolation levels defined as constants. Go to the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) and you can see the constants.

```
conn.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE );
```

NOTE: TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE might not be the one what you want. I suggest you read [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html).

**print readable string**

```
String getReadableLevel(int isolation)
{
String result="";

switch(isolation)
{
  case Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE: result="TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE";break;
  ...//u get the idea
}
return result;
}
```

Comment: yeah i read that from there only i thought i should set it as seriliazable as it prevents all the dirty read problem etc. But what about the integers and levels??? how do i find out what integer refers to which level cause if its already set as seriliazable it won't make sense to set it again right ;)

Comment: @Nav Yes it prevents all of that but is also with least performance/throughput...I am just making sure you are aware of the trade-offs. Also, if I answered your question then pls accept it as the answer

Comment: @Panga thank u for the answer +1 :)  but i wanted to know about the integer levels conn.getTransactionIsolation() how can i make this more readable cause i don't know what these integers refer to.E.x if it displayed that by default it supports TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED or something u know

Comment: you can write a utility method that takes the integer and returns a readable String representation of the isolation level. I updated the post with sample code

Comment: for that won't i have to know what level of isolation level each integer is mapped to???

Comment: @Nav you doesn't need to as i am using the constants from the Connection class itself...check my sample code